# defaultState in redux reducer changes

Tags: javascript, redux

I have a default state bellow,

```
const defaultState = {
  targetFilters: [
    {
      key:'Web version',
      type:'RANGE',
      uBound:'',
      lBound:'',
      tKey:'appBar.shopFilters.webVersion.name',
      tInfo:'appBar.shopFilters.webVersion.info',
    },
    {
      key:'Job status',
      type:'SELECT&RANGE',
      selections: ['Success','Unreachable'],
      uBound:'',
      lBound:'',
      sIdx:0,
      tSelections: ['dashboard.view.job.success.name','dashboard.view.job.unreachable.name'],
      colors:['#388e3c','#FF9F00'],
      tKey:'appBar.shopFilters.jobStatus.name',
      tInfo:'appBar.shopFilters.jobStatus.info',
   },
];
```

But I observed that the default state changed. I knew so because I printed it out in the update function and I found that the

> colors:['#388e3c','#FF9F00']

often changed to be

> colors:['#388e3c']

```
export function updateShopFiltersState(state=defaultState,action){console.log(defaultState);
switch(action.type) {
...
    default:
        return state;
}
```

}

I am really confused and don't know why. Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Do you have a reducer for `targetFilters`?

Comment: Thanks for comment. I do have one, and I also add console.log in it. But those codes have nothing to do with this issue since nothing is printed out.

Comment: I chose to use a workaround anyway. But any suggestions or ideas are still welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much.
The possible root cause may be that when I use the "colors", I use the colors "reference" like something bellow,

```
const {shopFiltersState} =store.getState();
let cur=shopFiltersState.targetFilters.find((f)=>{return f.key==='Job status'}),
    chartConfig={ 
                          colors: cur?(cur.colors):[], //directly use the colors reference; this line may be problematic
                         },
```

Unfortunately, later reference modification may cause a direct write to the array, so I change the writing to be

```
colors: cur?copy(cur.colors):[]
```